# XML Digital Signature created with XPATH keeps adding schema definition to every node

Tags: java, xml-namespaces, xpath-2.0, xml-signature

I have a simple XML and i signed the XML using XPATH query like //*[@isDigSignReqd = 'true']. Now, the signed XML contains the attributes like

**`xmlns="http://www.xyze.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`**

attached to every node. The XML signature validation occurs fine. But, can I remove these attributes. 
I'm pretty new to XML signing and all that. Please help.

This is how the XML looks like (part)

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><XService xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice ACPDTLRequest.xsd">
 <request xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <header xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <BANK_ID isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">DBS</BANK_ID>
   <LANGUAGE_ID isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">001</LANGUAGE_ID>
   <CHANNEL_ID isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">I</CHANNEL_ID>
   <LOGIN_FLAG isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2</LOGIN_FLAG>
```

---

Transforms are created like this.

```
final XPathFilter2ParameterSpec xp2Spec = new XPathFilter2ParameterSpec(
Collections.singletonList(new XPathType("//*[@isDigSignReqd='true']", XPathType.Filter.INTERSECT)));
List<Transform> transforms = new ArrayList<Transform>() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
         {
    add(sigFactory.newTransform(Transform.ENVELOPED, (TransformParameterSpec) null));
    add(sigFactory.newTransform(Transform.XPATH2, xp2Spec ));
        } };
```

---

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for the complete solution. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now, the signed XML contains the
>   attributes like
>
> `xmlns="http://www.xyze.org/xservice"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"`
>
> attached to every node. The XML
>   signature validation occurs fine. But,
>   can I remove these attributes.

**Yes, the provided XML document is equivalent to this:**

```
<XService xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice ACPDTLRequest.xsd"
          xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <request>
    <header>
      <BANK_ID isDigSignReqd="true">DBS</BANK_ID>
      <LANGUAGE_ID isDigSignReqd="true">001</LANGUAGE_ID>
      <CHANNEL_ID isDigSignReqd="true">I</CHANNEL_ID>
      <LOGIN_FLAG isDigSignReqd="true">2</LOGIN_FLAG>
    </header>
  </request>
</XService>
```

**Explanation**:

The default namespace is in force on all names of descendent elements and doesn't need to be specified on them.

**How to get rid of the unnecessary namespace nodes or declarations**?

Here is a simple XSLT solution, using the identity transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<XService xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice ACPDTLRequest.xsd">
    <request xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <header xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <BANK_ID isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">DBS</BANK_ID>
            <LANGUAGE_ID isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">001</LANGUAGE_ID>
            <CHANNEL_ID isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">I</CHANNEL_ID>
            <LOGIN_FLAG isDigSignReqd="true" xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">2</LOGIN_FLAG>
        </header>
    </request>
</XService>
```

**the result is**:

```
<XService xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice ACPDTLRequest.xsd"
          xmlns="http://www.xyzbe.org/xservice" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <request>
    <header>
      <BANK_ID isDigSignReqd="true">DBS</BANK_ID>
      <LANGUAGE_ID isDigSignReqd="true">001</LANGUAGE_ID>
      <CHANNEL_ID isDigSignReqd="true">I</CHANNEL_ID>
      <LOGIN_FLAG isDigSignReqd="true">2</LOGIN_FLAG>
    </header>
  </request>
</XService>
```

Comment: Hi Dimitre,  Thanks a lot for your response. I'm sorry i framed the question a little incorrectly. I meant to say, how can i remove the namespace declarations. The signed XML by default comes like this. Is there any way i can remove the declarations on every node and add them on just a parent node or root node?. As in is there any attribute or a line of code to be written in the signing process that will make these attributes disappear. Please let me know.

Comment: @Sunny: I edited my answer and now it includes a simple XSLT transformation that produces equivalent XML document in which the namespace declarations are stripped off all elements with the exception of the top element.

Comment: Thanks.. This helps. I'm wondering if i can create a Transform and add such a transform to the list of transforms to do this job.

Comment: @Sunny, I don't know your environment -- probably you can -- read the documentation. :)